# Regular polygon finding the circumference

Tags: polygons

Area of the 10 regular polygon is 770cm^2 and the gap between the parallel line is 30,8cm. Find its circumference. Yeah, I'm going to fail on this subject.

Comment: Do you  mean *decagon*?

Comment: Consider the ten triangles formed by linking each edge to the centre.

Comment: decagon sorry :D

Comment: "the gap between the parallel line"?

Comment: Yeah.. I really don't know but when I translate it comes out "The gap between the parallel line the sides 30,8 something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ten triangles formed by linking each edge to the centre as shown:

[image]

You should be able to get the base of the triangle from here, then the entire perimeter.

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciate.